# Keyboard with weird commands

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xinput

It happened before with other systems, and I even tested changing some parts of the input driver.
The problem is: My system sometimes decide to mess with my keyboard and some keys stop working (and then start working again). The keys: z, x, c, v, m, right shift, enter, ,, . and ;.
The capitalized versions of them are even worse to type in. I thought that my keyboard was broken, but then I tried to type: shift shift and v (both right and left shift at the same time) and then the system get a T. That was very strange, and it works with no problem, but I'm sure that r-shift + l-shift + v it's not meant to be a "T".
Some forums say that this is windows fast boot fault, but even with it disabled the problem doesn't go away.
Another strange thing that happens sometimes: When a key didn't work, if I hold it down, the buffer print a giant string of these keys after some time. (Ex: I type >, and the text box shows this: >>>...>>.>>>.

Comment: Your keyboard is dirty or broken.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get a new keyboard right away.

If you are on a budget, borrow a keyboard from a friend and try with that one. If that works, definitely get a new keyboard.

Keyboards have become pretty cheap. You can get one for about 12.- EUR, and for 25.- you get an excellent one from Cherry.

Comment: It's not the keyboard. I've tested it on Windows (I have dual boot) with the same machine and the keyboard had no problem. It works fine on windows and ubuntu. I only have this problem once in a week (not on the same day, so it's not the clock). I even tested the hardware to see if the keys are working, and they're working fine.

Comment: Having this problem once every week would not be worth the hassle to me just to save 12-25 EUR. I'd trash that thing. Just saying.